# How to always make text and images on same line when resizing the window by using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here is the effect I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX7Rz.png)

Hey, I am wondering how to position with text and images on same line only by using css? And if this is possible, how to always keep them on the same line when I am resizing the browser or using a different computer? Thank you!

Comment: Should that image stay the same size?

Comment: just use `float: right`

Comment: @Keith Hey I tried it. Images are responsive to both the width and height of the browser, whereas text is only responsive the browser height.

Comment: @StackSlave It does not need to be the same size. As long as the image and text are on the same line

Comment: another alternative is to use `display: flex` on the container

Comment: Aren't your pictures just black and white backgrounds and text?

Comment: @多一点点爱 No they are not

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display:flex;` for this:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; 
}
#flex{
  display:flex; align-items:center; padding:10px;
}
#icon{
  width:164px; height:164px;
}
```

```html
<div id='flex'>
  <p id='para'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <img id='icon' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvKY9.png?s=328&g=1' />
</div>
```